# OpenCL for searching a set?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I have a sorted set of arrays of unsigned shorts e.g:

```
12, 222, 333, 444, 555
78, 456, 123, 987, 231
```

I wish to find either the first or all of those arrays that match a set of given predicates: e.g: [idx[1] = 222, idx[3] = 444], would match the first row as the value at index 1 is 222 and the value at index 3 is 444.

Is this a task where I would see an advantage from running the search on the GPU via OpenCL?
The volume of data is 1 to 2 hundred million items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, if you have sufficient rows to make it worth the parallelization, you could test each row in separate kernel (since they are independent) and get a good speedup if you have e decent GPU.

Comment: Thanks, can you exit early form an operation like this on the gpu? For example: If I only wanted the first match

Comment: @jdoig: Unfortunately no, you cannot cancel all the threads in a thread block, they have to run until completion. You might try to have a global variable signalling termination and checking it at every K items. In any case, if you have a good GPU you will get a much faster execution time than on the CPU.

Comment: Thanks again Tudor. Could you point me to a link regarding the technique you mention there? (signaling termination by way of a global variable). I worry that if the first match is at index 1000 and the last is at index 150 million then the OpenCL route might turn out to be not as efficient and/or return a LOT more data than I'll actually need (and I hear moving data to/from the card is the slow part)

Comment: @jdoig: But what is the maximum length of a row?

Comment: Actually one of those is going to be an integer (the id), that's what I'm going to want to return.

Comment: Well then there is no problem with not exiting early, because the rows are very short. I suggest you run some tests and see how it goes before optimizing further.